# Error when installing xampp

Tags: xampp

I copied the xampp zip onto the desktop and executed this in a terminal:

`sudo tar xvfz xampp-linux-1.5.3a.tar.gz -C /opt`

When i tried to install xampp, I am getting this

```
error tar (child): xampp-linux-1.5.3a.tar.gz: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar (child): Error is not recoverable: exiting now
tar: Child returned status 2
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your location should point Desktop then.Goto terminal and type `cd Desktop` and then follow the steps.

Comment: I did it in the same way but i am getting the above error again.

Comment: See my updated answer.

Comment: Yep, I did it in the same way.still, i get my above error.

Comment: You have your file in Desktop right?Then just right click that file and select Extract here and then move it to /opt

Comment: Then create the directory `sudo mkdir /opt`

Comment: or go for this approach https://help.ubuntu.com/11.04/serverguide/C/web-servers.html

Answer (score 3):

**Installing XAMPP**

- Download the most recent version of XAMPP to your Home directory

  http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/xampp/xampp-linux-1.5.3a.tar.gz?download
- Extract the archive to **/opt** using sudo

  `sudo tar xvfz xampp-linux-1.5.3a.tar.gz -C /opt`
- Starting XAMPP

  `sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start`
- Stoping XAMPP

  `sudo /opt/lampp/lampp stop`

**Note:**

- You should extract the source from the same location from where it is placed.
- In your case you have it in your desktop.
- So get into Desktop first by running this command in terminal `cd Desktop`
- Now extract it by type this command
  `sudo tar xvfz xampp-linux-1.5.3a.tar.gz -C /opt`
- In case you have downloaded it to you home directory, Your terminal will be in the right location after you've opened it.

**Alternate way to Extract:**

- Right click your **xampp-linux-1.5.3a.tar.gz** file which is in Desktop and select Extract Here.
  [image]
- After extraction you will find **lampp** in your Desktop.
  [image]
- Right click on lampp and select Cut.
- Now you have to paste it in **/opt** so type **gksu nautilus /opt** in terminal
- It will Open **opt** folder,Right click and select paste.

Comment: I am not finding such dir in my computer.

Comment: @user7063 you don't need to write in all caps, we read every comment. :-) Have to tried following Karthick's instructions very closely? They should work.

Comment: The most recent version of xampp is 1.7.3a not 1.5.3a. You can get it from http://sourceforge.net/projects/xampp/files/XAMPP%20Linux/1.7.3a/xampp-linux-1.7.3a.tar.gz/download

Comment: Can you post a link for that beautiful conky script?

Comment: @lovinglinux yep i know that,but he is having version 1.5.3a that's why i have used that here.

Comment: The alternate way will not always work as extracted files will be owned by the active user (only root can change the ownership of files). LAMPP runs under the `nobody` user. Thus, mysql will not start because it can not write to the directory `/opt/lampp/var/mysql/`, neither will some components of LAMPP work (e.g. language selection), and so on.

Answer (score 0):

The most recent version of xampp is not 1.5.3, but 1.7.3a. So I suspect that is what you have downloaded. If that is the case, then use this command:

```
sudo tar xvfz xampp-linux-1.7.3a.tar.gz -C /opt
```

Anyway, verify that the command you are using matches the version of the file. Put the downloaded file in your home directory (e.g. /home/yourusername/), not a sub-folder or somewhere else and execute the command above, replacing the numbers with the corresponding version. If the downloaded file is located somewhere else, you will need to cd into that directory before using the command above, otherwise the tar command will look for that file in your home directory and won't find it.

Then follow this tutorial: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=223410

Comment: You can also just write the first few letters of the file name and press TAB, bash will try to automatically complete the file name if it exists in this location.

Answer (score 0):

### Installing XAMPP

Open the terminal.

You said you have placed the XAMPP archive on the desktop, so therefore you have to make sure that you have navigated to your desktop folder in the terminal:

```
cd ~/Desktop
```

Extract the files from the archive using the following command:

```
sudo tar xvfz xampp-linux-1.7.3a.tar.gz -C /opt
```

You would probably have to make sure that you have permissions to put files in XAMPP's web page directory:

```
sudo chmod a+rwx /opt/lampp/htdocs
```

### Starting the server

To start XAMPP, enter the terminal and type the following line:

```
sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start
```

Make sure that the server is successfully installed by navigating to http://localhost/. You should see a page that tells you that XAMPP was successfully installed.

To stop the server, just type this:

```
sudo /opt/lampp/lampp stop
```

### Setting up your web pages

Open the file browser and navigate to the `/opt/lampp/htdocs` directory. Place all your web pages in this directory.